# Gradle Cargo Plugin, not logging in Eclipse Console

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have this configuration in my build

```
local {
      homeDir = file('/opt/tomcat')
      outputFile = file('build/output.log')
      timeout = 60000
      containerProperties {
         property 'cargo.tomcat.ajp.port', 9099
      }
}
```

But when I remove "outputFile" logging does not appear in Eclipse Console. What can I do?

Comment: Did you try to run this from the command line? Do you see the output there?

Comment: No output with command line either. I would like to say that when i put "outputFile", tomcat 's Catalina.out appends ok in the file.

Comment: The prompt is like waiting with this message "> Building 98% > :cargoRunLocal" and tomcat start ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with [STS Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/wiki), you have two alternatives:

1. Go to **Window** >> **Preferences** and set **-i** argument as follows:

[image: Alternative 1]

2. Or you can set it directly by [Gradle Task UI](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/wiki/Gradle-Task-UI#the-gradle-task-ui-launching-gradle-tasks):

Right click on your project, then select **Run As** >> **Gradle Build..** and you must to do this:
[image: Alternative 2-1]

[image: Alternative 2-2]

Remember that you mustn't set any output file. So, you have to remove this line:

```
outputFile = file('build/output.log')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the appropriate messages from Cargo if you run your Cargo task with the info log level e.g. `gradle cargoRunLocal -i`.

Comment: It worked from command line, but i have no way to configure with Eclipse plugin. Do you know if there is a way to configure this level programatically in the build?

Comment: I think you should be able to provide command line options from Eclipse as well. It calls Gradle under the covers.